# Async Process Calls

Tags: asynchronous, process, ipc, d

What is the preferred way of calling other processes asynchronously in D? My use case is calling `svn status` checking exit status, and parsing its standard output and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [std.stdio.popen](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#popen) is what you want:

```
void popen(string command, in char[] stdioOpenmode = "r");
```

Use it with a `File` and you get the output; something like:

```
File f;
f.popen("svn status", "r");
char[] line;
string result;
while (f.readln(line))
    result ~= line;
return result;
```

Or you can use [std.process.shell](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#shell) which apparently does this for you (and throws an [ErrnoException](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_exception.html#ErrnoException) on error).